# HTTPD + JBOSS Communication using mod_jk

Tags: apache, ssl, jboss, load-balancing, mod-jk

I am configuring load balancing using `httpd` which will connect to `jboss` using AJP (`mod_jk` connector).

My Jboss is running using SSL and httpd is not with SSL.

How can I establish communication from *http httpd* to *https jboss*?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have enable https in httpd so that it can route to the https of jboss properly. And it has started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mod_jk, have you considered using mod_cluster? It fits well with JBoss and serves sticky session and session replication as well.

Comment: Appreciated your response. As per my business needs we need  not do session replication. Only load balancing and Sticky Session which mod_jk provides in better way...
Thanks a ton

Comment: @sitakant Could you elaborate what exactly do you feel mod_jk does better than mod_cluster? mod_jk offers a statically configured subset of what mod_cluster can do...